# Infrastructure for Automatic User Logon (SSO) with Active Directory / LDAP / NTLM

Tags: php, ldap, single-sign-on, ntlm, ezpublish

I have to set up an automatic logon system for an eZ Publish Website hosted on a debian server. The pitch is :

"a client is logged on its Windows session (User registered on a Windows Active Directory (so LDAP)) ; when he'll arrive on the intranet eZ publish website, he is detected by the browser (using NTLM...?) and the user is automatically logged on"

Apparently, an LDAP support is built-in eZ Publish, so, there's no issue for this part of the problem. The main issue is how can I retrieve current user login from the Windows session ? I've read different stuff about NTLM, but nothing explicit... and it seems that I have to install php5-ldap and ntlm-mod...? :( I know it's kinda tricky, but tips would be greatly appreciated ! :D

Thanks in advance;

Charly

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Legrandin/PyAuthenNTLM2

This apache module puts the windows user name into php variable $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'].